# Stack2RSS - A JSON to RSS Conversion Service [Now Fully Open Source!]

Tags: app, website, notifier, service

> ### New Location
>
> The site has moved here: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/

[image]

## Stack2RSS

### About

Stack2RSS is a small service that when given an API query, generates an RSS feed that you can then subscribe to in your RSS reader.

The inspiration for this application came from all of the feature-requests on Meta that I saw. All of the following are now solved by using Stack2RSS: *(a long list, I know...)*

- [RSS feed of hot questions during the week for specific tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/62364/rss-feed-of-hot-questions-during-the-week-for-specific-tag/64922#64922)
- [Could there be an RSS feed for the newest Featured questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/60891/could-there-be-an-rss-feed-for-the-newest-featured-questions/64923#64923)
- [RSS for Stack Overflow's unanswered questions that matches my only favorite tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57300/rss-for-stackoverflows-unanswered-questions-that-matches-my-only-favorite-tags/64924#64924)
- [Tags in RSS bodies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/56389/tags-in-rss-bodies/64925#64925)
- [How can I get an RSS feed of just my own questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/55868/how-can-i-get-an-rss-feed-of-just-my-own-questions/64926#64926)
- [RSS feed for new Stack Exchanges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/53945/rss-feed-for-new-stack-exchanges/64927#64927)
- [RSS feed for responses to your posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/21756/rss-feed-for-responses-to-your-posts/64928#64928)
- [Can I get Stack Overflow's user feeds, about only the answers.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/44161/can-i-get-stackoverflows-user-feeds-about-only-the-answers/64929#64929)
- [Anyway to get a RSS feed for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42525/anyway-to-get-a-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions/64978#64978)
- [Why is there no RSS feed for /unanswered/tagged/tagname?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/41696/why-is-there-no-rss-feed-for-unanswered-tagged-tagname/64979#64979)
- [How do you do to keep track of notifications?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40927/how-do-you-do-to-keep-track-of-notifications/64980#64980)
- [How often is the RSS feed updated?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/40804/how-often-is-the-rss-feed-updated/64983#64983)
- [Can I create an RSS feed of only my questions but that does not include answers I give to questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/34509/can-i-create-an-rss-feed-of-only-my-questions-but-that-does-not-include-answers-i/64984#64984)
- [RSS feed of reputation changes? Comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/28172/rss-feed-of-reputation-changes-comments/64986#64986)
- [RSS feed for favorite questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions/64987#64987)
- [Can we have other RSS feeds - the current one messes up outlook](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/18045/can-we-have-other-rss-feeds-the-current-one-messes-up-outlook/64989#64989)
- [Answer Only RSS feed for a user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14183/answer-only-rss-feed-for-a-user/64991#64991)
- [RSS feed for votes on user's questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/15262/rss-feed-for-votes-on-users-questions-and-answers/64992#64992)
- [RSS for unanswered+tagged questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13849/rss-for-unansweredtagged-questions/64993#64993)
- [Provide RSS feed for questions with >n votes or replies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5721/provide-rss-feed-for-questions-with-n-votes-or-replies/64994#64994)

### License

Now released under the GPLv3 license!

### Download

The easiest way to get a feel for what you can do with Stack2RSS is to visit its homepage at:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com

You can vote for your favorite feeds there and submit your own.

To actually use this service, simply format a URL as follows:

```
http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/{site}/{query}
```

- `{site}`  - the domain name of the site (for example, **superuser.com**)
- `{query}` - the API query to use (for example, **users/1**)

There is one extra parameter you can use that I should mention:

- `api_version=xxx` - forces Stack2RSS to use the given API version (currently this can be either `1.0` or `1.1`).

### Examples

Here are a couple of examples that demonstrate Stack2RSS usage:

- Unanswered PHP questions on Stack Overflow

  > http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/questions/unanswered?tagged=php&body=true
- Questions asked by Jeff Atwood on Super User sorted by votes:

  > http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/superuser/users/1/questions?sort=votes&body=true

### Platform

Any RSS feed reader.

### Contact

I can be contacted at **admin@quickmediasolutions.com**.

### Code

The code for this project [is now hosted on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/stack2rss).

Comment: Another service available: http://www.systemical.com/web-services/stackoverflow - built on Google AppEngine.

Comment: Hmm, seems to fail when trying view the timeline: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/superuser/questions/16933/timeline

Comment: @TheLQ: I'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: @TheLQ: It seems like the support for question timelines hasn't been added to Stack2RSS. If you need this functionality, please let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: @TheLQ: Never mind, I'm going to add it anyway.

Comment: @George No thats fine, I was just wanting to point that out. I haven't exactly found an easy way to use Stack2RSS, and it doesn't seem I can track a specific questions

Comment: @TheLQ: Did you see [this](http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/)?

Comment: @George thank you for this app and hosting of the rss feed, I use it quite a bit. As a suggestion, a link to SO API would be beneficial

Comment: @SiegeX: Where would you like to see a link to the API?

Comment: @George In the description on this page, somewhere near where you say *"you can just browse the site I set up"*. A link to the [API Docs](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) would be a good thing to have.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I just tried using [this feed](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/gaming.stackexchange/questions?sort=creation&body=true), and it seems that tags no longer appear in the body of the feed.

Comment: @YiJiang: You're right - tags should appear in the body of the feed. I'll try and get them added soon.

Comment: @YiJiang: It is now fixed in the code repository.

Comment: I'd love to use your great app, but I need a hint here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765036/use-stack2rss-to-receive-responses-via-rss :-)

Comment: Is it possible to get the question on which I answered, while fetching my answer only feeds?

Comment: @Starx: Try [this](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/847/answers?body=true).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, I meant question body.

Comment: This is an awesome app. Any thoughts about moving to the [2.x API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) which has many more parameters available?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: I'd like to - it's just that everything is so busy :)

Comment: Global favorites feed possible?

Comment: @KhurshidAlam: Unfortunately no, not with the current API.

Comment: As far as I understand, When a user star a question it will receive updates to it (edits, comments, and new answers) in json. Since this `favorite-rss-feed` was created on  this api it will also update & create new feed item upon any update. So whenever there is multiple edits on a single favorite question, it creates multiple new feed items of same question.And that's the problem. I am getting multiple notification for my old favorite-questions.Can it be sorted by date (`added`) like `stack2rss.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/users/11112/favorites?sort=added` ?

Comment: What I want is to get **only** new favorite questions in the feed.

Comment: What does it look like for a timeframe to update to V2 of the API? I don't have the time in the next 4 days to look at the source, but I was hoping to use Stack2RSS with IFTTT.

Comment: @Thomas: You have no idea how horrified I was to discover that I need to quickly update this :P There goes my Saturday :(

Comment: @NathanOsman Thanks! If I have time, this may encourage me to set up a local PHP environment. But there's no way I can get it set up and start doing anything on this before the API expires. I've got the capability to work on the JVM now, and getting C and C++ set up shouldn't be hard. I just haven't had a need to work with PHP.

Comment: @Thomas: Actually, I'll probably be rewriting it in Python since I've all but abandoned PHP development and moved to Python now.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I've got an early preview here for you: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/

Comment: @Jeroen: please read the notice at the top of this question.

Comment: @NathanOsman: my bad, sorry. Good luck on the updating, I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: @Jeroen: I have a working demo here, if you are interested in testing: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com

Comment: @NathanOsman: thanks, I'm using it now to follow specific users. When I do so I see that every entry starts with "<username> on <title>", Will you change this to just "<title>" as was the case with the previous version?

Comment: can I use this to fetch all of my activities in all of my sites? It seems not

Comment: @Ooker Nope - it only works on one site at a time.

Comment: The service appears not working currently.The example URLs give internal server error.

Comment: @alehro: try this: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com

Comment: That's what I'm trying:
http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/2.2/questions?site=superuser
The response page shows:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: @alehro Oh, sorry - I misunderstood. Yes, it seems my API key has hit the quota limit for the day.

Comment: Hmm... it's still not working for me.  I'd LOVE to use this to get an RSS feed of favorites I add... any update?

Comment: Would the MSE site be `metastackexchange` for the site parameter? P.S. apparently, the [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/) site doesn't work. It won't load.

Comment: Does work no more :(