# Format a list of questions

Tags: app, questions

The following quickie command line application formats a list of questions obtained from search results.

#### Requirements:

[Perl](http://www.perl.org/), [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON)

#### Usage:

1. Retrieve a list of questions from the API (from the [`/questions/{ids}`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/questions-by-ids) or [`/search`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/search) route, maybe others) into one or more JSON file.
2. Call the script on the JSON file(s).
3. Copy-paste the output into a post on `meta.*`.

#### Example:

```
wget -O list+recommendations-1.json 'http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/1.1/search?tagged=list;recommendations'
wget -O list+recommendations-2.json 'http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/1.1/search?tagged=list;recommendations&page=2'
wget -O list+recommendations-3.json 'http://api.scifi.stackexchange.com/1.1/search?tagged=list;recommendations&page=3'
show_questions https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ list+recommendations-?.json
```

Result: [this meta.scifi question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/411/1), e.g.

> - [What science fiction novels have well developed alien languages?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1) (8)
> - [What are the different types of robots in Total Recall 2070?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3) (0)
> - [I want to read Cyberpunk story, series or movie can you give me a list of good/famous ones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65) (6)
>     (…)

#### The script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

## Usage: $0 http://stackoverflow.com/ questions.json ...

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(slurp);
use JSON;

my $root = $ARGV[0]; shift; $root =~ s!/$!!;

my @questions =
  sort {$a->{question_id} <=> $b->{question_id}}
  map {@{$_->{questions}}}
  map {from_json(slurp($_))} @ARGV;

foreach my $q (@questions) {
    my $title = $q->{title}; $title =~ s/([*<>\[\]\`\\])/\\$1/g;
    my $url = "$root/questions/" . $q->{question_id};
    my $answers = $q->{answer_count};
    print "* [$title]($url) ($answers)\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 - I sure could have used this script [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s).